# Why is Mysql Workbench refusing to accept the original root in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, root, mysql-workbench

I just installed a new mysql-server and Mysql Workbench in Ubuntu 20.04 The server worked fine although it was necessary to use `sudo` to login the root. Nevertheless, the Mysql Workbench refused to connect to the database server (*Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'*) and only when I replaced the original root (as described in the [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196135/2104392)), the workbench eventually accepted the new one. What exactly is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default root is configured with `unix_socket` authentication. Basically speaking if a database user (in this case root) is configured this way it does NOT use a password. The only way to logon is if you are that same unix/linux user.

So your mysql workbench is not running as root so therefore it's not possible for it to login as the root database user. By changing the authentication method to password authentication you solved your problem but possibly made the database more insecure.

Often the root database user would remain as unix_socket authentication for security reasons and you would just create whatever other database users with whatever permissions are required.

Here is a good article on the subject:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/